# Перенаправление в начало страницы при перезагрузке от нажатия кнопки

Tags: php, html, post, form, submit

Обычно при перезагрузке страницы ты остаешься на том же месте что был до перезагрузки (если ничего не менял) и у меня все так и работает и это хорошо, но. У меня на сайте есть кнопки в формах, которые отправляют пост запрос на эту же страницу. При этом происходит перезагрузка страницы и перенаправление на начало страницы и это уже плохо. Мне нужно чтобы после нажатия на кнопку я остался ровно на том же месте что и до нажатия. Сделал пример на [html-game.site/primer.php](http://html-game.site/primer.php) там внизу кнопка, ее код:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="1" value="Это обычная кнопка input в форме">
</form>
```

**Спасибо за ответ, вот само решение, оно реализовано на jquery:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var scrl, storage;
storage = sessionStorage.getItem('value');
console.log('Session storage: ' + storage);

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, storage);
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  scrl = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log('Scroll position: ' + $(window).scrollTop());
  sessionStorage.setItem('value', scrl);
});
</script>
```

Можно сразу копировать в любую часть файла и все будет работать, **а этот код фиксирует как по вертикали так и по горизонтали:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var scrlY, scrlX, x, y;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  scrlY = $(window).scrollTop();
  scrlX = $(window).scrollLeft();
  sessionStorage.setItem('valueY', scrlY);
  sessionStorage.setItem('valueX', scrlX);
});
y = sessionStorage.getItem('valueY');
x = sessionStorage.getItem('valueX');
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var scrlY, scrlX, x, y;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  scrlY = $(window).scrollTop();
  scrlX = $(window).scrollLeft();
  sessionStorage.setItem('valueY', scrlY);
  sessionStorage.setItem('valueX', scrlX);
});
y = sessionStorage.getItem('valueY');
x = sessionStorage.getItem('valueX');
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.scrollTo(x, y);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает как надо, везет же когда знаешь js

Comment: @Maxbend пожалуйста, отметьте ответ принятым (галка), если он вам помог

Answer (score 0):

https://snipp.ru/html-css/save-scroll-position Тут описано 3 варианта и если есть только такие варианты, то это печалька.

1. AJAX мне использовать неудобно, да и тем более придется переписывать кучу кода, хотя видимо это самое адекватное решение.
2. Якоря вообще не варик так как нужно чтобы страница оставалась в том же месте что и до нажатия на кнопку пиксель в пиксель
3. Через `<input type="hidden">` выглядит как костыль да и у меня слишком много кнопок, так что тоже гемор.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scrl, storage;
storage = sessionStorage.getItem('value');
console.log('Session storage: ' + storage);

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, storage);
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  scrl = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log('Scroll position: ' + $(window).scrollTop());
  sessionStorage.setItem('value', scrl);
});
```

Comment: Добавил скрипт прямо в код в тегах <script>...</script> в начале кода и в конце попробовал - не помогло.

Comment: jquery - подключал? Или нужен ванильный?

Comment: Не подключал, после подключения заработало, спасибо!

Comment: Но я забыл про горизонтальную прокрутку, на сайте-примере ее нету, но на рабочем сайте есть, мне нужно чтобы и по горизонтали экран оставался на месте.